# Bootstrap popover appears although it should be hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, onclick, click, hide, popover

Hey what I'm trying to do is following:

I have different buttons for a level selection for a browser game. Each button stands for one level. After the user selects a level he has to click the START button to go to the chosen level. `var level` gets the value of the certain level button. e.g. user chooses level one, so `var level = 1`;

When he clicks on the START button without choosing a level there'll appear a popover with the content "choose a level first". To hide the popover by clicking anywhere or by clicking on a level button I use the following code. At the beginning `var level = undefined` and only then the popover can be called. After the user chose a level `var level` is not undefined anymore and the popover cannot be called again.

So far so good.

The popover appears by clicking on the START button without choosing a level and disappears by selecting a level. But when the user now clicks on the START button the popover appears again. How is this possible?

```js
$('#start').bind("click touchstart", function(e) {
    if (level==undefined) {
        $('#start').popover();
        isVisible = true;
        clickAway = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$(document).bind("click touchstart", function() {
    if(isVisible && clickAway) {
        $('#start').popover('hide');
        isVisible = false;
        clickAway = false;
    } else {
        clickAway = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" rel="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Choose level first!" value="" id="start" name="start">START!</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix would be to change `$('#start').popover('hide');` to    `$('#start').popover('destroy');`
also add `data-trigger="manual"` to the button

Below is the way which I have implemented this scenario,

```
 $(document).bind("click touchstart", function(f) {
  if(f.target.id!="start"){
   if(isVisible)
   {
     $('#start').popover('destroy');
     isVisible = false;
   }
  }  
   else if (level==undefined && !isVisible) {       
    $('#start').popover('show');
    isVisible =true;
  }  
  });
```